# How can I debug minidlnad installed via snap?

Tags: 18.04, snap, minidlna

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and I installed minidlna via snap because of the several dependencies that I don't otherwise need, and to avoid dependency hell.

I edited /var/snap/minidlna-escoand/19/minidlna.conf and I checked in the log file that everything goes well:

```
[2019/05/01 18:42:06] minidlna.c:1048: warn: Starting MiniDLNA version 1.2.1.
[2019/05/01 18:42:06] minidlna.c:1089: warn: HTTP listening on port 8200
```

However, I checked with VLC and no media is available.

The config file shows:

```
media_dir=/tank/media/Videos
media_dir=/tank/media/Music
media_dir=/tank/media/Photos
media_dir=/tank/home/olaf/Anime e manga
```

and the permissions are:

```
root@ml110g7:~# ps aux | grep minidlna
root     ...  minidlnad -f /var/snap/minidlna-escoand/19/minidlna.conf -P /var/snap/minidlna-escoand/common/minidlna.pid
root@ml110g7:~# ls -l /tank/media/
total 27
drwxrws--- 13 root music  14 Feb 27 23:22 Music
drwxrws---  4 root photos  7 Feb 27 23:22 Photos
drwxrws---  9 root videos 10 Feb 27 23:22 Videos
```

minidlnad runs as root, so why isn't it able to access the folders? one of the folders contains spaces (something that should pose no problem), but the other ones are simpler and no error is logged.

How can I debug the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [`Ubuntu MiniDLNA` instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA)

```
#network_interface=eth0         # Self-discovers if commented (good with NetworkManager)
media_dir=V,/tank/media/Videos    # Use A, P, and V to restrict media 'type' in directory
media_dir=P,/tank/media/Photos
media_dir=A,/tank/media/Music
db_dir=/var/cache/minidlna      # Needs to be un-commented
log_dir=/var/log                # Needs to be un-commented
inotify=yes                     # 'no' for less resources, restart required for new media
```

> Restart the daemon for changes to take effect:

```
sudo service minidlna restart
```

> To rebuild the database use:

```
sudo service minidlna force-reload
```

> ## Firewall Rules
>
> If using a firewall the the ssdp (1900/udp) and trivnet1 (8200/tcp) ports will need to be opened. For example this can be done with arno's iptables firewall by editing firewall.conf to:

```
  OPEN_TCP="8200"
  OPEN_UDP="1900"
```

You need to make sure that the problem is with `MediaDLNA` and not `VLC`.
The [following guide explains how to access the files with `VLC`](https://superuser.com/a/262180/693836).

MiniDLNA uses `tcp` port `8200` so you should be able to access the page at `http://localhost:8200` with your browser [as explained in this installation guide](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/06/openhome-media-minidlna-bubbleupnpserver/). If you can access the files, then you misconfigured `vlc`.

Opening `miniDLNA` content with your browser will help you understand if the issue is connected to [VLC or MiniDLNA](https://sourceforge.net/p/minidlna/discussion/879957/thread/e4bc879e/).

Comment: I think you missed the part where I refer to "snap". This is not a normal install, therefore I don't know how or if I can execute the "force-reload". However I checked the web interface and it works. It just shows zero media files, and that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the minidlna snap has known issues with media folders:

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/minidlna/6318/9

The author hasn't solved the issue yet, therefore I cannot continue using that snap.